# Creating a template and possibly macros for flashcards on MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, microsoft-word-2013

I've played around with creating two styles (different text sizes, alignment, etc.), one for each side of an index card, but it doesn't allow me to set vertical alignment. Do I have to make a macro to combine applying a style and vertical alignment or is there a setting to have Word automatically do this for alternating pages?

Regarding vertical alignment, after I hit Page Break or Blank Page on page 1 to move to the next page, it moves the text one line up, so it wasn't centered anymore. I have to keep putting my cursor at the end of the text and hitting delete to move it back down. Is there something else besides Page Break/Blank Page that'll avoid this?

Short gif illustrating the issue: [http://i.imgur.com/e59goXX.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/e59goXX.gifv)

Comment: I'm trying to replicate the problem you're getting, and I'm not seeing it. When I add a section break or page break after text that's vertically centered, it stays centered.  To start with, I recommend turning paragraph marks on so you can see if you're getting an extra hard return before your text that would move it down.

Comment: Hi Kelly. I'm not sure if the formatting has any effect on it, but to provide the circumstances under which I experience the problem, the size of the page is 3x5, orientation is set to Landscape, the font size is 22 and it is centered horizontally as well as vertically. I made a quick gif of what happens when I hit either Page Break or Blank Page with the paragraph marks on. http://i.imgur.com/e59goXX.gifv

Comment: That looks centered to me, and I'm not seeing the page break mark on there.  Is it the next page it's showing up on?

Comment: At the end of the gif, I move the cursor back to the end of the text on page 1 and hit delete to center it again. It jumps up one line when I insert a break/blank page.

Answer (score -4):

I love the templates [this tool](https://flashcard.online/) provides. [here](https://flashcard.online/flashcard-template/) are some ready templates for flashcards to use

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.